# Which Modernizr css class determines if translateX() can be used?

Tags: css, css-transforms, modernizr

I'm coding a slide in drawer menu using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, and Modernizr (for feature detection).

I'm targeting the latest 5 browsers plus IE8 and up, and am using `transform: translateX(x)` (not supported by IE8) for the drawer animation (slides in from left off-screen.)

I'd like to use Modernizr to detect whether `transform: translateX(x)` is available but am not sure if `transform: translateX(x)` is a '2D Transform' or a '3D Transform'.

Question is: which Modernizr CSS class (set in the page `<body>` tag) should be used?

The Modernizr CSS choices are:

`csstransforms` or `csstransforms3d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translateX()` is a 2D transform. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX) does not explicitly state this anywhere, while the now-defunct [WebPlatform.org](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/translateX()) says:

> ### Summary
>
> Transform function for a 2d translation which moves an element on the x-axis by the given value.

and in the css-transforms spec, it's listed under [§15.1 2D Transform Functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#two-d-transform-functions).

Comment: Ok, so Modernizrs `csstransforms` should perfectly indicate whether `transform: translateX(x)` is an available option for the browser being used by the visitor?

Comment: I wouldn't say "perfectly" but in general, yeah.